# How can I register a username for YouTube?

Tags: youtube, google-account, username

My friend has a Google Account, `iwantthis`. She has the `iwantthis@gmail.com` e-mail address, but at registration, she wasn't able to register the `iwantthis` YouTube name, insted she has `iwantthisplussomething`.

I checked `youtube.com/iwantthis` and it responds with 404, so it seems like nobody is using it, neither a Google+ public profile exists.

Is it possible to register (or put in practice) the YouTube name `iwantthis` somehow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

YouTube seems to be cleaning up inactive accounts. There have been a couple accounts that I have followed personally as to await when they will be deleted. As of recently, they have all 404'd, which means YouTube closed these accounts due to inactivity.

On that note, I would also assume the same rules applies to when one closes their account manually, *you will not be able to register for the same username again*. That is, it appears to be taken but the account has been closed and it is not being released back to public.

*Why is this so?* Not sure, as with other Google products, Google is very stubborn (imho) when it comes to allowing users to change their username.

Answer (score 1):

If it's possibly a registered trademark, has been banned, or the user closed it. The other possibility is that the username was registered & used before Youtube was purchased by Google.

Google won't allow the reuse of a username that's been used before. (Sources: [one](http://groups.google.com/a/googleproductforums.com/forum/#!category-topic/youtube/accounts-sign-in-and-sign-up/skKpWyTaEJY), [two](http://groups.google.com/a/googleproductforums.com/forum/#!category-topic/youtube/accounts-sign-in-and-sign-up/ZpMzDdtm-3s), [three](http://groups.google.com/a/googleproductforums.com/forum/#!category-topic/youtube/how-to-use-youtube-features/bWctyJCXXPo))

Likely, this account was created before the requirement that a youtube account be tied to a Google account.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that Google may not allow the same username on both Gmail and YouTube.

I don't know for sure though.

Comment: Welcome to the WebApps Stack Exchange. While your answer is appreciated it's preferred that answers contain provable facts. Guesses are typically frowned upon.