# How long does Google keep deleted IDs

Tags: gmail, google-account

If I deleted my Google account, I cannot register a new account with the same name.

How long does Google keep that name taken, before I can register it again?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I doubt you'll be able to use the username again. Google restricts this throughout their applications (I just gave an [answer to a youtube username question](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/25083/17743)).

You do have a short amount of time to recover your deleted account, though. See [Deleting or restoring a Google Account](http://support.google.com/accounts/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=32046)

Comment: +1 The answer to "How long does Google keep..." is *FOREVER*.

Comment: Ahh, yes... the tl;dr version